# Series of LegendreP[a,b,x] takes ages in Mathematica 11

Tags: special-functions, series-expansion

My institution just upgraded to Mathematica 11.3 (from v10) and I'm experiencing a problem that is absent in Mathematica 10. Namely,

```
Series[LegendreP[a, b, z], {z, -1, 0}]
```

takes ages to run, whereas the same command in Mathematica 10 is evaluated almost instantaneously. Is this a bug? Did someone reported somewhere?

Comment: On MMA `11.3` its probably a bug,The proof is: `Series[LegendreP[1, b, z], {z, -1, 0}, 
 Assumptions -> {b \[Element] Integers, b > 0}]` gives: ``2^(1/2 b Floor[Arg[-1 - z]/(2 \[Pi])] - 
  1/2 b (1 + Floor[Arg[-1 - z]/(2 \[Pi])])) (1 + z)^(b/2) (
SeriesData[z, -1, {
SeriesDump`SafeSeries[Indeterminate, {-1, -1, 2 + Rational[1, 2] b}]},
    0, 1, 1])``